# Upload error to appfog: "Error (JSON 404): not found"

Tags: ruby, json, http-status-code-404, appfog

I'm using appfog service for my grails app. I used `af` ruby utility from them for couple weeks and it worked fine. Today I've tried to update my project by command as usally:

```
af update my_project
```

But recived an error:

```
Error (JSON 404): Not Found
```

I don't know what i broke, but at another computer i do the same and it works.

How to fix it? And maybe you know what i broke?

Comment: currently appfog is having some problem, it's reated to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213692/appfog-error-when-updating

Answer (score 3):

Met the same issue.

It seems I was logged out. Had to log back in and worked justed fine.

```
af login
  > Email: ...
  > Password ...
af update my_poject
```

Bang! Worked!

Comment: Our of topic, but unhappy that Appfog has removed custom domain name for free plans I therefore moved to Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

It was happening with my Django app too, because my local copy was empty.

I could fix it downloading from github, a blank django project (should have for grails too) for appfog

https://github.com/appfog

So I could update that files and run the command again:

```
af update my_project
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone. I had forgotten that I changed the project name to something else, so make sure you are updating to a project that actually exists like so:

```
sudo af update project
```

Also make sure you are logged in:

```
sudo af login
```