# AppFog error when updating

Tags: node.js, npm, cloud-foundry, appfog

I always get this error when I'm updating my files in my appfog cloud hosting.

```
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (7K): OK   
Push Status: OK
Stopping Application 'volkova': OK
Staging Application 'volkova': OK                                               
Starting Application 'volkova': .
Error: Application [volkova] failed to start, logs information below.

====> /logs/stderr.log <====

./startup: line 3: /opt/cloudfoundry/runtimes/nodejs-v0.6.17/bin/node: Permission denied
```

What is the cause of this and how can I prevent this?

Comment: Is this still an issue? or was it the same error described by Igo below?

Comment: I always receive this issue when I'm trying to run linux commands using nodejs child_process. I tried removing those codes and my application works. But when I put them back, this happens again. I am doing chmod and npm install, because last time I did an update, the files were too big so what I did is let the npm packages be installed in the cloud. And this kind of error happens when I do chmod and npm install commands.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error about 3 days ago. Problem is in AppFog. They have fixed it next day. I also noticed that this error was not occurring in other data centers.